# MacBook Pro 13" Touch bar - Privacy > Accessibility list not working

Tags: mojave, settings, privacy

My MBP with Mojave 10.14.6 doesn't let me add apps to the Privacy > Accessibility nor to Privacy > Full Disk Access in the System Preferences > Security & Privacy pane.

Many devices ask me to do this during initial setup (e.g. my Wacom tablet). As a result many things don't work properly (the Wacom tablet doesn't work at all,   Dropbox only works partially, etc).

How do I solve or reset Mojave in order to make allow the System Preferences > Security & Privacy pane to work properly?

So far, I've tried following the steps outlined on [Wacom's website](https://www.wacom.com/en-us/support?guideTitle=Why-is-the-Pen-and-Touch-functions-not-working-on-Mac-OS-10.14%3F&guideId=015-478), but without success.

Below is a screenshot of what I see when accessing the System Preferences > Security & Privacy pane.

[image: Security and Privacy Settings]

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask you to edit your question to clarify where it is you're running into problems following the steps on Wacom's website? Otherwise we're just guessing at to what's happening.

Comment: As I said before my MBP does not let me add apps to the Privacy>Accessibility list; The Wacom Driver is just an example of them. I've experienced the same issue with Apps like Dropbox, CleanMyMac and Duet that prompt the system message but unfortunately Nothing happens once I click the Allow button in order to let the app Control the computer.

Comment: What happens if you drag the apps in, or add with the + button? Both ways should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, Nothing happens, it's very rare look at this video I just did to illustrate the issue: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pm7lmj8gtaotb0l/Screen%20Recording%202019-09-25%20at%2012.37.18%20PM.mov?dl=0